# Hopfield - incorrect recognition

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

Im trying to code Hopfield pattern recognition network, which can recognize digits from binary maps. The problem is: in 90% results I'm getting the same blob (not even a specific pattern, just noise).
Anyone coud explain me what ma I doing wrong?
I have Hopfield net with 81 neurons and 10 patterns. Training mthod: Hebbian.
I've implemented my own net, but also found other implementation.

Patterns:

```
piec = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1,
        1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
siedem = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
          -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1,
          -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

szesc = [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
         1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1,
         -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]

dziewiec = [-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1,
            -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]

zero = [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1,
        -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1,
        -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

jeden = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
         -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
         -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, ]

trzy = [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, ]

dwa = [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
       -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1,
       -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1]

cztery = [-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
          1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
          -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
wzorce = list()
wzorce.append(zero)
wzorce.append(jeden)
wzorce.append(dwa)
wzorce.append(trzy)
wzorce.append(cztery)
wzorce.append(piec)
wzorce.append(szesc)
wzorce.append(siedem)
wzorce.append(dziewiec)
```

Network:

```
import numpy as np

class InvalidWeightsException(Exception):
    pass

class InvalidNetworkInputException(Exception):
    pass

class HopfieldNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, num_inputs):
        self._num_inputs = num_inputs
        self._weights = np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (num_inputs, num_inputs))

    def set_weights(self, weights):
        """Update the weights array"""
        if weights.shape != (self._num_inputs, self._num_inputs):
            raise InvalidWeightsException()
        self._weights = weights

    def get_weights(self):
        """Return the weights array"""
        return self._weights

    def evaluate(self, input_pattern):
        """Calculate the output of the network using the input data"""
        if input_pattern.shape != (self._num_inputs, ):
            raise InvalidNetworkInputException()

        sums = input_pattern.dot(self._weights)
        s = np.zeros(self._num_inputs)

        for i, value in enumerate(sums):
            if value > 0:
                s[i] = 1
            else:
                s[i] = -1

        return s

    def run(self, input_pattern, max_iterations=200):
        """Run the network using the input data until the output state doesn't change
        or a maximum number of iteration has been reached."""
        last_input_pattern = input_pattern
        iteration_count = 0

        while True:
            result = self.evaluate(last_input_pattern)
            iteration_count += 1
            if np.array_equal(result, last_input_pattern) or iteration_count == max_iterations:
                return result
            else:
                last_input_pattern = result
```

Training:

```
def hebbian_training(network, input_patterns):
    """Train a network using the Hebbian learning rule"""
    n = len(input_patterns)
    num_neurons = network.get_weights().shape[0]
    weights = np.zeros((num_neurons, num_neurons))
    for i in range(num_neurons):
        for j in range(num_neurons):
            if i == j:
                continue
            for m in range(n):
                weights[i, j] += input_patterns[m][i] * input_patterns[m][j]
    weights *= 1/float(n)
    network.set_weights(weights)
```

And "main":

```
import random
def mutate_wzorzec(wzorzec, mutacje=0):
    for _ in range(mutacje):
        do_mutacji = random.randint(0, len(wzorzec))
        wzorzec[do_mutacji] *= -1
    return wzorzec

import wzorce81 as wzr
input_patterns = np.array([np.array(x) for x in wzr.wzorce])
network = HopfieldNetwork(81)

hebbian_training(network, input_patterns)
mutacje=[]
for wzor in input_patterns:
    mutacje.append(mutate_wzorzec(wzor))
shape1=9
shape2=9
for i, mutacja in enumerate(mutacje):
    wynik = network.run(np.array(mutacja))
    mutacja.shape=(shape1,shape2)
    wynik.shape=(shape1,shape2)

    plt.subplot(5, 4, 2*i+1)
    plt.imshow(mutacja, interpolation="nearest")
    plt.subplot(5, 4, 2*i+2)
    plt.imshow(wynik, interpolation="nearest")
```

Feel free to copy it, and create verdict...

Comment: `anyone coud explain me what ma I doing wrong?` <- you are using spellcheck and grammar check incorrectly, in that you are not using them. Further, you have not said anything about the specific nature of the failure of your network to recognize patterns. In addition, you haven't said anything about what the expected output is, so even if I run the code, I'll have no idea what to expect

Comment: Does the same "wrong" thing happen with your implementation and the one you found? What does wrong mean? An error? Not the results you hoped for?

Comment: Sorry, I've accidently deleted the first part of my post, that's why it starts from lowercase letter.